# Reverse a saved course on Garmin Edge 200?

Tags: garmin

If I've saved a course to my Edge 200, can I reverse it to get back to the start? Or do I need to save two versions?

The "back to start" option only seems to be there when I'm already following a course, not when I'm about to set off. Which isn't that helpful if you've stopped for a while.

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of a way to do this using just the Garmin unit.  However, if you have a computer handy, then you can upload your ride to one of the many GPS cycling sites (for example, http://ridewithgps.com/ works well for this).  Once the ride is online, you can reverse the route using tools on the website.  You'll want to then verify that everything is as you expect because sometimes the route reversal can cause unexpected detours ;-)  Then you can save the reversed route back to your Garmin unit to guide you on your next ride.